# How to change an image in a .dll file

Tags: c#, dll

So I have an .dll file which I know is written in C#.

I used JetBrains *dotPeek*, to decompile the .exe and inside the .exe I can see a folder called **Images** and then inside that folder around 10 images some of which **I would like to change**.

I understand that dotPeek is just for decompiling I think. So after googling this I came across two programs, *Resouce Hacker* and *ResTuner*, which both said they could edit images inside a dll file. So I opened this dll file up in both and in both programs all it showed was one folder called "Version Info"

Is there a different program which can do this?

Comment: Maybe this works http://fishcodelib.com/Resource.htm

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27373/File-Resource-Management-Library-NET

Comment: Woah whats with the massive downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've done a bit more research and came across this program called **https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/wiki**

This program does exactly what I want it to do and not only allows me to edit images but also strings of text as well as remove certain lines of code.

The program has a nice user interface and automatically finds refrences and opens up the respective dlls when going through the code. It also allows you to search all open files for specific strings which allowed me to easilt find the code controlling various features.

Comment: This sounds like an advertisement

Comment: well I answered the question because what I found was eactly what I wanted

Comment: Advertisement or not, I just discovered dnSpy because of this post and color me impressed. The program is gorgeous and very powerful. I can't even benefit from it as much as others since I'm not a .NET developer, but it just replaced my previous hex editor, HxD.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned the tool you are using to accomplish this task.

In general, you can use Visual C++, MFC to open the .dll in the Resource format. It will separate all the components of the .dll including the image(s).

Replace the image and save the .dll

Comment: _"You did not mentioned the tool you are using to accomplish this task"_ - actually he mentioned two.  .NET assemblies don't embed resources the same way as native .dlls do so you can't use Visual c++ resource editor